# One process which spawns two threads on a Two-Cores Machine under GIL

Tags: python-3.x, multithreading, cpu

Suppose I have one process which spawns two threads on a Two-Cores Machine.

Because of the GIL,

Is it possible that thread-1 is bound to Core1 while thread-2 bound to Core2, thus they are waiting to get their lock on different CPU.

Or all the threads constantly bound to a particular CPU, (even though 100 threads spawn on a 100-cores machine).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Threads by default are not bound to any CPU -- when a thread is ready-to-run, the OS will dynamically dispatch it to run on an available core using an algorithm of the OS's choosing.

Because the GIL is Global, however, only one thread in a given Python process can ever be executing Python byte-codes at any given time.  Any other threads in that process will be blocked waiting to acquire the GIL, and thus will not be associated with any core at all.

Comment: So a thread could run on a distinguished core from the process in which the thread spawn.

Comment: It's probably better to think of a process as a memory-space which one or more threads share access to.  In that memory-space you have the 'main thread' (which is launched for you by the Python interpreter when the process starts) and any other threads that you're code explicitly launches.  There is no difference, core-scheduling-wise, between the main thread and the additional threads.

Comment: ty very much, I wait a while and accepted the answer this night.